# How to Fetch record from DB using entity in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I've got three tables joined with each other - Quote, quotevehicle and vehicle. I want to get record of all vehicles and their quotes. Those vehicles whose quote is not should return empty quote. So far it's giving record of only Vehicle table and if I try to get record of quotevehicle table or quote it gives error: Attempted to call method "getQuote" on class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

**Structure of quotevehicle**
id   quote_id   vehicle_id

**Controoler**

```
        $qb = $om->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('MinicaspVehicleBundle:Vehicle', 'v')
            ->select('v', 'b')
            ->leftJoin('v.quoteVehicle', 'b')
            ->orderBy('v.id', 'ASC')
    ;
```

**Vehicle entity**

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 */
protected $seats;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45)
 */
protected $fleet;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45)
 */
protected $regNo;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $auto;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $fuel;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
protected $notes;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $make;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $model;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $wheelChairsNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
 */
protected $courierSeats;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
 */
protected $wc;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=45, nullable=true)
 */
protected $chassis;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=true)
 */
protected $engineCapacity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $additionalCosts;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
protected $motLicense;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $motLicenseStart;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $motLicenseExpiry;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 */
protected $insurancePolicy;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $insurancePolicyStart;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $insurancePolicyExpiry;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $nextServiceDate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $nextInspectionDate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $roadTaxExpiry;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", unique=true, nullable=true)
 */
protected $isDefault;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $isActive = true;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $fleetmaticsData;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VehicleCat")
 */
protected $vehicleCat;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VehicleFile", mappedBy="vehicle", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $vehicleFiles;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Probus\QuoteExtraBundle\Entity\QuoteVehicle", mappedBy="vehicle", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 */
protected $quoteVehicle;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Probus\QuoteExtraBundle\Entity\Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
protected $tags;
```

**QuoteVehicle Entity**

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quote", inversedBy="vehicles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $quote;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Minicasp\VehicleBundle\Entity\Vehicle")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 */
protected $vehicle;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Minicasp\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver")
 */
protected $driver;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $driverConfirmed = false;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $textDriver = false;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $emailDriver = false;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $textCommutingDriver = false;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $workTicket = false;
```

**Quote Entity**

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuoteVehicle", mappedBy="quote", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $vehicles;
```

Comment: I expect this is a typo but your description and code reference 'quotevehicle' but the title of your quotevehicle code is 'VehicleQuote'. Is the title a typo or did you name the entity class incorrectly?

Comment: When you say 'if I try to get record of quotevehicle table or quote it gives error', what is the error?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't using this?: $vehicles = $vehicleRepository->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'ASC'));

Comment: its a typo error in title.

Comment: error is Attempted to call method "getQuote" on class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Comment: getQuote function is written in quotevehicle entity to get quote record

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message 'Attempted to call method "getQuote" on class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"' it sounds as though you are trying to execute something like this on the entities returned by your query:

```
$quote = $vehicle->getQuoteVehicle()->getQuote();
```

The Vehicle entity's $quoteVehicle is a one-to-many and therefore is a Collection of QuoteVehicles. Naming it $quoteVehicles would be more accurate, make the code clearer and help to avoid errors.

You need something like:

```
foreach($vehicle->getQuoteVehicles() as $quoteVehicle)
{
    $quote = $quoteVehicle->getQuote();
    ...
}
```